# Select from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible directly in phpmyadmin in sql form to select from 10 tables at once? 
In my database I have 10 tables: `table1`, `table2`, ... `table10`. I have same column in them `column1`. Records in that column always starts like `123...` and always is 12 symbols length.
What I want to do is to select from those tables records that doesn't start with `123` and they are <12 symbols length.

Is it possible this?

Comment: Post your attempt as well along with sample data and desired output!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "UNION"

Comment: I don't have anything in mind how to be done this condition something like `SELECT column1 FROM table1,table2,...table3 WHERE...`. I really have no idea what will be after WHERE caluse.

Comment: @RC. I've checked `UNION` and seems is what I need but still I can't figured it out how to give this condition in sql query: `show me record that doesn't start with 123 and is <12 symbols`

Comment: can you provide your sql tables will give you better solution !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below query is what you're looking for

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT column1, 'table1' table_name from table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, 'table2' table_name from table2
UNION ALL
... --repeat for all 10 tables
SELECT column1, 'table10' table_name from table10) 
where column1 not like '123%' and length(column1) < 12;
```

This will return results like this:

```
column1      table_name

abc          table2
1245yy       table5
```

This will give you all the records from each table where column1 does not conform to the conditions of length and format.

**EDIT:**

Many thanks to [jarlh for this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521854/select-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql#comment49120424_30522264) Using `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION` is safe (and with performance boosts) because if the column1 happens to not have a unique index, then duplicate values coming from one table will be dropped. For some extra reading on the performance bonuses of using UNION ALL, [check this link.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/)

Comment: please mark as an answer thanks @codeNewbie

Comment: Any reason to not use UNION ALL instead?

Comment: @jarlh: The only plus to using `UNION ALL` would be the performance improvement. But since I'm including the table name as another column, no record will be missed out in the final result.

Comment: That's only true if none of the UNION's SELECTs return any duplicates. (I'd say always do UNION ALL as long as you haven't decided to remove duplicates.)

Comment: @jarlh: Thank you for your input. :) Truly a valuable contribution.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer and accept. Can I just ask what is for `table_name` in every select?

Comment: The `table_name` column is one that I have created, so that you can easily decipher which table that particular invalid value came from, in case you are going to work with (or without) those invalid values.

Answer (score 1):

as per your Q and my understanding of this Q

```
select table1.column1, table2.column1, ... table10.column1 from 
table1, table2, ... table10 where 
table1.column1 = table2.column1 and
table2.column1 = table3.column1 and .....
table9.column1 = table10.column1 and
table1.column1 not like '123%'
and table2.column1 not like '123%'.....
and len(table1.column1) < 12, len(table2.column1) < 12....
```

Comment: This will result in a cross join, which is totally going to throw the OP off track.

Comment: @CodeNewbie he didn't mention anything in Q he just want result which not start from 123 and < 12

Comment: You won't be giving him a result, you will be giving him a cross join of the valid results, which can't logically be used to do anything else.